# optimizing mysql subquery execution time

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, execution-time

I have a following query:

```
select
qs.*
from
    (
        select
            tsk.id,
            tsk.request_id,
            tsk.hash_id
        from
            user_tasks as usr
            inner join unassigned_tasks as tsk on usr.task_id = tsk.id
        where
            usr.assigned_to = 53
            AND tsk.product_id NOT IN (
                SELECT
                    product_id
                FROM
                    product_progresses
                WHERE
                    request_id = tsk.request_id
            )
        ORDER BY
            tsk.id
    ) as qs <-- this takes about 233ms.
WHERE
    qs.id = ( <-- should this subquery execute for every row from outer result-set row?
        SELECT
            min(qt.id)
        FROM
            (
                select
                    tsk.id,
                    tsk.request_id,
                    tsk.hash_id
                from
                    user_tasks as usr
                    inner join unassigned_tasks as tsk on usr.task_id = tsk.id
                where
                    usr.assigned_to = 53
                    AND tsk.product_id NOT IN (
                        SELECT
                            product_id
                        FROM
                            product_progresses
                        WHERE
                            request_id = tsk.request_id
                    )
                ORDER BY
                    tsk.id
            ) as qt <-- this takes about 233ms.
        WHERE
            qt.id > 83934
    )
```

Both `qs` and `qt` takes about the same time to execute, i.e. around `233ms`.

Also, executing this whole query takes about the same time.

I have a conception that inner query inside `where qs.id = (...)` executes once for every row in the result-set generated from `qs`.

In this current case, `qs` outputs `10` rows.

So I decided to test if the sub-query is executed for each row 10 times.

Here's what I put inside sub-query:

```
WHERE qs.id = (
    SELECT
        SLEEP(1)
)
```

instead of `where qs.id = ( select min(qt.id) ... )`.

This took about `10.246` s which proves that the inner query is being run for each row.

So with this, shouldn't the initial query take about `(qt time) 233 * 10 (rows from qs)` = `2330`ms?

Is it because `select min()..` is calculated once only?

Comment: I'm trying to find documentation to support this, by in my experience MySQL tends to execute every subquery first.  I.e. Because `qs` is subquery, it'll be fully evaluated, rather than limited by there `where` clause.  But if you move the where clause inside `qs` it will limit the selection.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL subqueries within the `FROM` clause are evaluated before subqueries in the `WHERE` clause.

Useful article:
https://www.eversql.com/sql-order-of-operations-sql-query-order-of-execution/

In your case, this is causing `qs` to be fully evaluated before the `WHERE` clause is factored in.  If you want `qs` to be limited by `qt` you should be able to achieve that by unnesting `qs` or moving `qt` inside `qs`.

In practice though, rather than use a subquery for the `WHERE` clause, it would be probably better to use joins.

See [SQL select only rows with max value on a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column)